Why does two disk system with windows mirroring fail to boot when primary disk removed?
I am evaluating replacing hardware RAID1 with windows server 2019 disk mirroring. This is because i want to migrate to NVME disks and our hosted server provider has advised windows disk mirroring is superior to hardware RAID1 for NVME disks.
I can setup the mirrored disk fine, i've recreated the partitions, copied the boot partition files, mirrored the windows and data partitions. Once the primary disk has been mirrored ( or as mirrored as possible because windows can't mirror the boot partition ), the system will happily continue if i disconnect either of the drives ( but not both of course ). Additionally if the system is rebooted with secondary drive missing, it boots up fine. However if the system is rebooted with primary drive missing ( eg. simulating it failing and being replaced with a blank disk ) then the system fails to boot. Is this failure to boot from secondary disk an architectural limitation of windows disk mirroring or have i missed some aspect of setting up the disks ?

Windows RAID1, in the context of OS booting, isn’t a true RAID1 and shouldn’t even be called that! What Windows actually does, it creates a second copy of your boot drive and adds an option to the boot menu to let you boot from the second copy if your primary copy is damaged. However, if your first drive fails so badly that you can’t reach the boot menu, you’re out of luck! The second copy is essentially useless since it’s not independently bootable.
One alternative is to use pseudo-hardware RAID solutions like Intel’s vROC (Virtual RAID-on-Chip). Although it’s technically still software RAID because it uses the SATA/SAS ports on your motherboard and doesn’t include dedicated RAID controller hardware (like CPUs to handle firmware and offload parity calculations, dedicated PCI buses for internal XOR traffic, etc.), it has two advantages: a) It’s OS-independent (as long as your OS has a compatible driver, of course), and b) It remains bootable even if one of the disks in your RAID1 set fails.
Another option is to use a dedicated boot device like the Dell BOSS card, which is essentially a mini-RAID controller designed for a couple of flash drives. It’s built specifically for safe booting and serves no other purpose.
Hope this helps. Good luck!

Windows has been that way for over 25 years. Software RAID is rare due to hardware RAID controllers are inexpensive, and over 95% of hosts are virtualized these days. The few organizations that use software RAID on Windows typically must have the recovery procedure documented in the event of the storage failure of a single host.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/set-up-dynamic-boot-partition-mirroring#establish-a-mirror-from-the-boot-volume-to-the-secondary-drive
